# Run project problems using Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, git

I have cloned repository from bitbucket.org (it is my repo). But now I can't run this project.

I made next:
Import -> Project from Git
then I follow the importing guide but maybe I selected something wrong. So I can see all files in project tree that I have cloned but can't run it. What's the problem?

When I select Run As in menu I don't see any option (only Run configuration), but I want to see Run as Android project.

[image]

I also try add project using Run configuration but I don't see my ea project in Project selection list.

Comment: I don't think Eclipse is seeing it as an `Android` project. When you clone from git, at the last step of the importing wizard, try and selecting `Create a new Project` and select an android project.

Comment: I try it using wizard and it works good thanks!

Comment: Ok, cool. I'm going to put it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Eclipse is seeing it as an **Android** project. When you clone from git, at the last step of the importing wizard, try and selecting **Create a new Project** and select an android project.